# Editing the navigation bar (Appbar) on a Thingsboard flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, thingsboard

I am new to developing using flutter and the dart language, but I am converting a thingsboard website into an app using flutter in android studios. I have followed this guide to get to where I am now:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/pe/mobile/getting-started/

And I have basically downloaded the source code and altered the endpoint to go towards my website, so not a lot of dev work has gone into this so far. The source code for flutter is here:
https://github.com/thingsboard/flutter_thingsboard_pe_app.git

[Here is the current app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwajA.png)

Within this picture I have circled the top bar and the bottom bar in the screen in red, they are both inbuilt features that I cannot seem to change. I have looked all through the code to try and change them but I can't seem to find it. I have a feeling that it is being taken from a class that is in the source code of flutter as opposed to this project in particular and I assume I have to call it in order to change the features, however I cannot find much documentation on the matter to help. I would like to at least figure out how to change the colour of these bars or something so then I know that they are editable and I can begin working on altering them to display what I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried the following things:

1. I tried to find the code within the project that built these features, I thought I found it and there was a colour attribute, so I changed this colour. I expected the colour of the app bar to change but nothing changed.
2. I  found a file called tb_app_bar and I changed the colour set within this, I was expecting the app bar to change colour but nothing changed.
3. I saw something called systemUIoverlay was called, so I added code into the main script that called this and disabled it, I was expecting this to get rid of the features but nothing changed again.

I am beginning to think the way it should be done is by calling to a class and setting the properties this way, but I'm really not too sure

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have included a link to the github page that I downloaded the source code from

Answer (score 0):

**I have partially solved this problem**

Within the file:

> lib/widgets/tb_app_bar.dart

There is a class that creates the app bar:

```
class _TbAppBarState extends TbContextState<TbAppBar> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
    
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
    children.add(buildDefaultBar());
    if (widget.showLoadingIndicator) {
      children.add(ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: loadingNotifier,
        builder: (context, bool loading, child) {
          if (loading) {
            return LinearProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            return Container(height: 4);
          }
        }
      ));
    }
    return Column(
      children: children,
    );
  }
    
  AppBar buildDefaultBar() {
    return AppBar(
      leading: widget.leading,
      title: widget.title,
      actions: widget.actions,
      elevation: widget.elevation ?? 8,
      shadowColor: widget.shadowColor ?? Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withAlpha(150),
    );
  }
}
```

To alter the background colour of this I added the following line:

```
backgroundColor: Colors.red,
```

To the `buildDefaultBar()` function:

```
AppBar buildDefaultBar() {
  return AppBar(
    leading: widget.leading,
    title: widget.title,
    actions: widget.actions,
    elevation: widget.elevation ?? 8,
    shadowColor: widget.shadowColor ?? Color(0xFFFFFFFF).withAlpha(150),
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  );
}
```

The other part of this problem is how to access the bottom widget, so any help with this would be appreciated

**Final solution**

To delete the bottom bar I had to change the following code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  TbMainNavigationItem.changeItemsTitleIntl(_tabItems, context);
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      if (!await tbContext.willPop()) {
        return false;
      }
      if (_tabController.index > 0) {
        _setIndex(0);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
    child: Scaffold(
      body: TabBarView(
        physics: tbContext.homeDashboard != null
          ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
          : null,
        controller: _tabController,
        children: _tabItems.map((item) => item.page).toList(),
      ),
      // bottomNavigationBar: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
      //   valueListenable: _currentIndexNotifier,
      //   builder: (context, index, child) => BottomNavigationBar(
      //     type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      //     currentIndex: index,
      //     onTap: (int index) =>
      //       _setIndex(index) /*_currentIndex = index*/,
      //       items: _tabItems
      //         .map((item) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
      //           icon: item.icon, label: item.title
      //         ))
      //         .toList()),
      //   )
      // );
    }
```

And comment out the lines that have been commented.